# Visual C++ 2010 atomic types support?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, atomic

Does VC++ 2010 have support for C++11's portable atomic type template?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No; none of the C++11 atomic operations or thread support features are supported by Visual C++ 2010.

Both of these sets of features are supported by Visual C++ 2012.

Comment: How evil. Do I have an alternative to the C++0x version, then?

Comment: @Electro:  There is no truly portable alternative.  Compiler support is required for an atomic operations library to ensure that optimizations don't violate the atomicity of the operations.  You might look into [just::thread](http://www.stdthread.co.uk/) which implements the C++0x threads library and (at least parts of) the atomics library for a handful of platforms, including Visual C++ 2010 (it is not free, but also not particularly expensive).

Comment: I am aware compiler support is required for it - well, thanks anyway, and I'm not prepared to spend money to license that for my open source engine.

Comment: Boost 1.5.3 provides atomic types. See: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/atomic.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use [tbb::atomic](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/).  It is not the same as C++0x atomics, and is not really meant to be a replacement or temporary substitute for them, but can be used to accomplish the same programming tasks.

Answer (score 2):

InterlockedExchange,  InterlockedIncrement and InterlockedDecrement might be of use to you while we wait for VC++ 2012 to wrap them up in standard-compliant wrappers.

Comment: I agree. Despite having the latest (vs12/cl18) I still have 2010 based projects I must work with.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the Concurrency Runtime. It's far more comprehensive than the offerings from the C++ standards committee, and comes in VC10. That is, of course, not particularly portable, but if you want that, then Intel's Thread Building Blocks can work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Boost or a commercial option is http://www.stdthread.co.uk/